# Why my Menu Items didn't replace to my Custom Design ( Android )?

Tags: android, xml, menuitem

I have three menu items in my app and i want to change the background image , text color and font for all items but nothing getting changed.

This is the following code.

**Java Code -:**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) 
{

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.custom_menu, menu);

    getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() 
    {

        public View onCreateView(String name, final Context context,
                AttributeSet attrs) 
        {

            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView")) 
            {

                try 
                {
                    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);

                    final View view = li.createView(name, null, attrs);



                    new Handler().post(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {

                    ((TextView) view).setTextSize(30); 

                    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/arialbd.ttf");     

                    ((TextView) view).setTypeface(face);

                    ((TextView) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white6);

                    ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

                        }

                    });


                    return view;

                }
                catch (InflateException e) 
                {



                }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
                {



                }

            }


            return null;

        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

 }     


 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{

    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
    case R.id.abc:
           break;
    case R.id.xyz:
         break;
    case R.id.exit:
         break;
    }
    return false;

}
```

**XML Menu Code-:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/abc"
    android:orderInCategory="10"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="ABC"/>


 <item
    android:id="@+id/xyz"
    android:orderInCategory="10"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="XYZ"/>


  <item
    android:id="@+id/exit"
    android:orderInCategory="10"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Andi"/>   

</menu>
```

and i want to keep all the **android:showAsAction="always"**  , please let me know , what is the problem? Suggest me some good solution.

Answer (score 0):

as i see you want to create and options menu that is doing some changes on your text, color, bg image etc.. when you click on and menu option right ?.

First of all why do u have two     **`onCreateOptionsMenu`**     functions, is the first one in super class or so in an activity extended class how canu extend it too. İ think u can do it in simpley way.

Create your menu items and put your     **`@Override (d) onCreateOptionsMenu`**     function in your class and call a different method which are doing different jobs e.g **`changeColor()`** for *abc*, **`changeThem()`** for *xyz*,     **`changeBGImage()`** for *qwe* and so on...

and let me give u some links that are doing this way and i

http://www.mustafasevgi.com/2012/08/android-de-optionsmenu-olusturma.html
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/12/android-app-menus/ (*this site has more*)

just check these sites if you have time..

You can see they are calling methods in the options switch case blocks for each action.

btw iam not and android developer but curiosity.

hope helps

regards.